# viewflipper get the current display child id

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have viewFlipper with three views insdie,

1. v1.id = 0
2. v2.id = 1
3. v3.id = 2

How could I know/get the current view id ?

i have textbox which i need to update according the current view id

`getDisplayedChild()` returns sometimes numbers bigger then 3 like 4, 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add only those three views only. i think you are adding views again and again so that the view's will be repeated and id will be more than 3. check your code again.

Comment: ok i found my mistake, I had  three <include> tag inside the viewFlipper

Answer (score -2):

If you really need an id and not an index, then `viewFlipper.getCurrentView().getId()` should work. Also it looks like you really have more than 3 views in your flipper.